# When does Eclipse xml editor show element documentation if you hoover over it

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, xml-editor

How is it with xml editor and documents that have xsd available ? I remember pop-up documentation when I was hoovering over the elements, but I haven't seen it for past months...

I'm using Eclipse indigo Java dev edition. XML Editors & tools installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the documentation for the XML element you need to have:

1. The XML namespace for the xml element must be configured using the xmlns attribute.
2. The namespace for the XMLSchema-instance must be configured (usually uses the xsi namespace prefix)
3. The xsi:schemaLocation must be configured for all necessary namespaces
4. The network preferences for Eclipse must have proper proxy configuration if you are behind an HTTP proxy as I am.
5. Perform a right mouse click validate on the XML file.  This will bring in the necessary schemas from the internet.  Fix any errors you have.

After that you should see the element documentation as you hover over elements or as you are entering new elements.